# Jquery sliding left menu with icon

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a menu with css and jquery which should show an icon for each menu item and if user hover  menu item for 0.5 sec, then it should slide left slowly to show the name of menu.. what I mean actually is something similar to [this plugin](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/RockingRollingMenu/). I prepared a [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d8qodv8t/2/). Since I am pretty new to web frontend development I could not further on it. I ask help from you. Thanks.

```
<div id="menuDiv">
    <a href="#" id="home">App Home</a>
    <a href="#" id="help">Help</a>
    <a href="#" id="photos">See photos</a>
    <a href="#" id="mail">Send a Mail</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not go through the tutorial you linked? That way you could actually learn what's going on, and how to reproduce it?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have checked it actually but i was lost in js and css files.. ok if nobody will help me, i will try to do it.

Comment: At least give it a try, and then post the code you come up with. I think once you show a bit of effort on your part, people will be more willing to help.  Best of luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a solved question of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28662262/let-displaynone-elem-slideright/28743132#28743132

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You will make "some" changes in Your code

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d0qpbhf3/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="menuDiv">
    <a href="#" id="home">
        <span class="menuIcon"></span>
        <span class="menuText">App Home</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="help">
        <span class="menuIcon"></span>
        <span class="menuText">Help</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="photos">
        <span class="menuIcon"></span>
        <span class="menuText">See photos</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" id="mail">
        <span class="menuIcon"></span>
        <span class="menuText">Mail</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    background-color: #E2E2E2;
}

*{
    padding :0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#menuDiv{
    padding:5px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}

#menuDiv a {

    background: pink;
    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    float: right;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#menuDiv .menuIcon {

    width: 48px;
    height: 48px;
    float: left;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

#menuDiv a#home .menuIcon {
    background: url("http://3.ii.gl/e95k6KER.png") no-repeat left center;
}

#menuDiv a#help .menuIcon {
    background: url("http://3.ii.gl/E-E-GRnJt.png") no-repeat left center;
}

#menuDiv a#photos .menuIcon {
    background: url("http://3.ii.gl/saNZbewlk.png") no-repeat left center;
}

#menuDiv a#mail .menuIcon {
    background: url("http://3.ii.gl/eOns-8L.png") no-repeat left center;
}

#menuDiv .menuText {
    width: 100px;
    height: 48px;
    line-height: 48px;
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    left: 48px;
}

#menuDiv a:hover {
    width: 148px;
}

#menuDiv a:hover .menuIcon {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-1440deg);
    transform: rotate(-1440deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is almost what I needed. However I would like not to open menu text suddenly.. if hover is for 0.5 sec then it should opne the text otherwise it should not open it.

Comment: So, just set `transition-delay`. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition-delay.asp

Comment: It works perfectly.. ok :) my last question. Some of my menu items are too long for width: 100px; and i dont want to make it 200px because some other menu items would be too short for 200px.. do you know how to make the width just wrap the text?

Comment: I think, then You must rebuild my code. CSS transitions, from/to `auto` width are not supported by browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without js using css 3 transition delay, like:

```css
body{
 background-color: #E2E2E2;
}
*{
 padding :0px;
 margin: 0px;
}
#menuDiv{
 padding:5px;
 background: yellow;
 display: inline-block;
}

#menuDiv a{
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 width:48px;
 line-height: 48px;
 white-space:nowrap;
 margin: 8px;
 text-indent:50px;
    
    -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .5s;
    -o-transition-delay: .5s;
    transition-delay: .5s;
    
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    
      -webkit-transition-property: text-indent;
      -moz-transition-property: text-indent;
      -o-transition-property: text-indent;
      transition-property: text-indent;
}
#menuDiv a:hover {
    text-indent: 0;
}

#menuDiv a#home{background: pink url("http://3.ii.gl/e95k6KER.png") no-repeat left center;}

#menuDiv a#help{background: pink url("http://3.ii.gl/E-E-GRnJt.png") no-repeat left center;}
#menuDiv a#photos{background: pink url("http://3.ii.gl/saNZbewlk.png") no-repeat left center;}
#menuDiv a#mail{background: pink url("http://3.ii.gl/eOns-8L.png") no-repeat left center;}
```

```html
<div id="menuDiv">
 <a href="#" id="home">App Home</a>
 <a href="#" id="help">Help</a>
 <a href="#" id="photos">See photos</a>
 <a href="#" id="mail">Send a Mail</a>
</div>
```

In this example, I animate the text-indent, adapt as you wish.